# Gitlab: Make user that creates a repo a maintainer?

Tags: gitlab

I want any user in our Group that created a new repository to automatically have maintainer rights for that repo.

I can't find any administrative settings on Gitlab.com that would imply the ability to do this automatically.

I have all users in the group set to "Developer" privileges on all repos but I'd like to have the user that created the repo to be set as "Maintainer" upon repo creation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but here is the idea.

Setup a System Hook for `project_create` event:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/system_hooks.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/system_hooks/system_hooks.html

In hook body `owner_name` is hopefully the creator.
So in your script you can then make an API call to promote user:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html#add-a-member-to-a-group-or-project